# Does it EVER make sense to make an array property?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, properties

[According to MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229054(v=vs.100).aspx), methods should be used instead of properties when they return an array. They further go into reasoning why this is the case with a concrete example.

However, there are a couple of cases I can see where this seems a bit extreme of a view.

### CASE 1

The property is on a data container and the rest of the data are properties. It is very unlikely that the property will ever be refactored to generate a new array per request.

```
public class Foo
{
    private readonly int[] bar;
    private int fooish;

    public Foo(int[] bar, int fooish)
    {
        this.bar = bar;
        this.fooish = fooish;
    }

    public int[] Bar
    {
        get { return bar; }
    }

    public int Fooish
    {
        get { return fooish; }
    }
}
```

### CASE 2

A class's public fields are being refactored into properties (to at least provide the illusion of encapsulation).

```
public class Foo
{
    public int[] Bar { get; set; }
    public int Fooish { get; set; }

    // Other members...
}
```

My question is - is there any realistic argument for making these into methods if I know they are backed by a field (and likely always will be)?

> **Background**: I am porting a library that others will consume from Java into C# and trying to come up with some kind of rule of thumb when to use properties and when not to (since in Java they are either methods or fields). Unfortunately, the widespread use of public array fields in the application makes the decision difficult - do I really need to make methods `GetBar()` and `SetBar(int[] bar)` if I know for certain it should always act like an array variable? Or in this case should these public fields remain as public fields in .NET rather than making properties? (yuck)

Comment: I never had public array property. that seems weird but if I ever want to do that I return a new copy or read only list `=> bar.ToList().AsReadOnly()`

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't always assume that the application's author intended these public array fields to be read-only. Some of them have documentation that specifically states they should *never* be null (which is an argument for making a setter in that case) which means they can be set by end users.

Comment: I've always found the no arrays as properties rule odd when lists, collections and read only collections are considered fine as properties. In the MSDN article it make sense not to have a property where you clone the array contents, but if its just the array itself I've never seen an issue with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, the guidelines you mentioned are for designing class libraries - if your code will be consumed by other developers they are much more important than when used within an application you maintain.

The problem with arrays is that callers can modify the elements within - I don't think exposing arrays as public fields just because of these guidelines makes alot of sense (no offense) because it does not solve that issue.

Where possible you could expose them as `IReadOnlyList<T>`:

```
private int[] arr;
public IReadOnlyList<int> Arr { get { return arr; }}
```

If the application *does* require that callers can change the contents of the arrays, you should *definitely* avoid using a method, as that would make it even more obscure:

```
class MyClass
{
    private int[] arr;

    // can't clone the array, because your application requires the caller to change elements
    public int[] GetArr() { return arr; }
}

...

// very unclear for the caller that he's actually modifying the array on the obj instance
int[] values = obj.GetArr();
values[2] = 12;
```

In that case `obj.Arr[2] = 12;` is more intuitive.

Comment: I updated my question to reflect that this is a library that is being ported.

Comment: The MSDN link mentions "Use a method where the operation returns an array because to preserve the internal array, you would have to return a deep copy of the array" so in case you _want_ users of your library to modify the array, you won't give them a copy of the array and there is no need for a method. So I'd say `IReadOnlyList<T>` for properties they're not supposed to change, and `T[]` properties when they are. You might want to be specific about this in the doc comments of those properties.

Comment: Thanks. This was helpful. I ended up with a 3rd case because there were also methods in the application that returned arrays. Some were obviously meant to be written to. I couldn't really make any assumptions about the rest, so I just left them writable properties. I wasn't able to use `IReadOnlyList`, but thanks anyway for the advice.